# Why I'm getting stack smashing?

Tags: c, multithreading, stack

I'm trying to solve the Dinning Philosophers using C, and not only my threads do not stop when I philosopher die, but I'm also getting stack smashing, here is my code:

```
//main.js
static void create_threads(
    pthread_t *threads, pthread_t *death_threads,
    t_philo *philos, int n)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, dinning_handler, &philos[i]);
        pthread_create(&death_threads[i], NULL, death_monitor, &philos[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return ;
}

static void join_threads(pthread_t *threads, pthread_t *death_threads, int n)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        pthread_join(death_threads[i], NULL);
        i++;
    }
    return ;
}

static void destroy_mutexes(pthread_mutex_t *forks, t_philo *philos, int n)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&forks[i]);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&philos[i].last_meal_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&philos[i].eating_mutex);
        i++;
    }
    return ;
}

static void free_resources(
    pthread_t *threads, pthread_t *death_threads,
    pthread_mutex_t *forks, t_philo *philos)
{
    free(philos);
    free(forks);
    free(threads);
    free(death_threads);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_mutex_t *forks;
    pthread_t       *threads;
    pthread_t       *death_threads;
    t_philo         *philos;
    int             max_eats;
    pthread_mutex_t alive_mutex;

    validate_args(argc, argv);
    max_eats = -1;
    if (argc > 5)
        max_eats = ft_atoi(argv[5]);
    forks = NULL;
    threads = NULL;
    death_threads = NULL;
    philos = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&alive_mutex, NULL);
    if (!init_philos(&philos, &forks, argv, max_eats, &alive_mutex))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (!init_threads(&threads, &death_threads, ft_atoi(argv[1])))
        exit_gracefully(philos, forks);
    create_threads(threads, death_threads, philos, ft_atoi(argv[1]));
    join_threads(threads, death_threads, ft_atoi(argv[1]));
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&alive_mutex);
    destroy_mutexes(forks, philos, ft_atoi(argv[1]));
    free_resources(threads, death_threads, forks, philos);
    return (0);
}
```

Maybe the problem is here, in the fact that I have one monitor per philosopher

```
//initialize.c
#include "philo.h"

static void fill_philos(
    char **argv, pthread_mutex_t **forks, \
    t_philo **philos, int max_eats, pthread_mutex_t *alive_mutex
)
{
    int i;
    int n_philosophers;
    int someone_die;

    n_philosophers = ft_atoi(argv[1]);
    i = 0;
    someone_die = 0;
    while (i < n_philosophers)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&(*forks)[i], NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&(*philos)[i].last_meal_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&(*philos)[i].eating_mutex, NULL);
        (*philos)[i].id = i + 1;
        (*philos)[i].eats = 0;
        (*philos)[i].eating = 0;
        (*philos)[i].someone_die = &someone_die;
        (*philos)[i].time_to_eat = ft_atoi(argv[3]);
        (*philos)[i].time_to_sleep = ft_atoi(argv[4]);
        (*philos)[i].time_to_die = ft_atoi(argv[2]);
        (*philos)[i].max_eats = max_eats;
        (*philos)[i].left_fork = &(*forks)[i];
        (*philos)[i].right_fork = &(*forks)[(i + 1) % n_philosophers];
        (*philos)[i].alive_mutex = alive_mutex;
        i++;
    }
}

int init_philos(
    t_philo **philos, pthread_mutex_t **forks, \
    char **argv, int max_eats, pthread_mutex_t *alive_mutex
)
{
    int n_philosophers;

    n_philosophers = ft_atoi(argv[1]);
    (*philos) = malloc(sizeof(t_philo) * n_philosophers);
    if (!(*philos))
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mError trying to create philosophers\033[0m");
        return (0);
    }
    (*forks) = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t) * n_philosophers);
    if (!(*forks))
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mError trying to create forks\033[0m");
        return (0);
    }
    fill_philos(argv, forks, philos, max_eats, alive_mutex);
    return (1);
}

int init_threads(
    pthread_t **threads, pthread_t **death_threads,
    int n_philosophers
)
{
    (*threads) = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * n_philosophers);
    if (!(*threads))
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mError trying to create threads\033[0m");
        return (0);
    }
    (*death_threads) = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * n_philosophers);
    if (!(*death_threads))
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mError trying to create death threads\033[0m");
        return (0);
    }
    return (1);
}
```

```
//thread_handler.c

#include "philo.h"

static void eat(t_philo *philo)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->eating_mutex);
    philo->eating = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->eating_mutex);
    print_green("is eating", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
    pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->last_meal_mutex);
    gettimeofday(&philo->last_meal_time, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->last_meal_mutex);
    ft_usleep(philo->time_to_eat);
    philo->eats++;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->eating_mutex);
    philo->eating = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->eating_mutex);
}

static void p_sleep(t_philo *philo)
{
    print_blue("is sleeping", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
    ft_usleep(philo->time_to_sleep);
}

static void assign_fork(t_philo *philo, \
pthread_mutex_t **first, pthread_mutex_t **second)
{
    if (philo->id % 2 == 0)
    {
        (*first) = philo->left_fork;
        (*second) = philo->right_fork;
    }
    else
    {
        (*first) = philo->right_fork;
        (*second) = philo->left_fork;
    }
}

int dead_loop(t_philo *philo)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(philo->alive_mutex);
    if (*philo->someone_die == 1)
        return (pthread_mutex_unlock(philo->alive_mutex), 1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(philo->alive_mutex);
    return (0);
}

void    *dinning_handler(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_t *first_fork;
    pthread_mutex_t *second_fork;
    t_philo         *philo;

    philo = (t_philo *)arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->last_meal_mutex);
    gettimeofday(&philo->last_meal_time, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->last_meal_mutex);

    first_fork = NULL;
    second_fork = NULL;
    while (!dead_loop(philo) && (philo->max_eats == -1 || philo->eats < philo->max_eats))
    {
        assign_fork(philo, &first_fork, &second_fork);
        pthread_mutex_lock(first_fork);
        print_blue("has taken a fork", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
        pthread_mutex_lock(second_fork);
        print_blue("has taken a fork", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
        eat(philo);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(second_fork);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(first_fork);
        p_sleep(philo);
        print_blue("is thinking", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
    }
    return (NULL);
}

void    *death_monitor(void *arg)
{
    t_philo *philo;
    long    elapsed_time;
    int     is_eating;

    philo = (t_philo *)arg;
    while (!dead_loop(philo))
    {
        usleep(10000);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->eating_mutex);
        is_eating = philo->eating;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->eating_mutex);
        if (is_eating)
            continue ;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->last_meal_mutex);
        elapsed_time = get_elapsed_time(&philo->last_meal_time);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->last_meal_mutex);
        if (elapsed_time > philo->time_to_die)
        {
            print_red("died", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
            pthread_mutex_lock(philo->alive_mutex);
            *philo->someone_die = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(philo->alive_mutex);
            break ;
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

```
//time_handler.c
#include "philo.h"

long    get_elapsed_time(struct timeval *start)
{
    struct timeval  now;
    long            elapsed_time;

    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    elapsed_time = (now.tv_sec - start->tv_sec) * 1000 + \
    (now.tv_usec - start->tv_usec) / 1000;
    return (elapsed_time);
}

long    get_ts_in_ms(void)
{
    struct timeval  time;

    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    return ((time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000));
}
```

```
//utils.c
void    exit_gracefully(t_philo *philos, pthread_mutex_t *forks)
{
    free(philos);
    free(forks);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void    ft_usleep(int ms)
{
    long int    time;

    time = get_ts_in_ms();
    while (get_ts_in_ms() - time < ms)
        usleep(ms / 10);
}
```

I know that the code has memory leaks, but I'm aiming to solve after I solve this stack smash problem.

EDIT: Here are some logs that i get using lldb and the thread sanitizer flag:

```
* thread #2, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100000000)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001833b5a90 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_joiner_prepost_wake + 84
    frame #1: 0x00000001833b3bc4 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_terminate + 300
    frame #2: 0x00000001833b3a98 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_terminate_invoke + 92
    frame #3: 0x00000001833b6740 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_exit + 112
    frame #4: 0x00000001833b6040 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 148
```

```
ThreadSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==49995==ERROR: ThreadSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000100000000 (pc 0x0001833b5a90 bp 0x00016b623f60 sp 0x00016b623f10 T300488)
==49995==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
ThreadSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
ThreadSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
```

Comment: Stack smashing usually means you're writing out of bounds of an array. Using a tool like `valgrind` can help find these.

Comment: @Barmar, or running a build compiled with `-fsanitize=address`

Comment: There's a lot of code here, relative to the somewhat lacking description of what you've done to investigate the issue. There is no sample input to reproduce the issue either. Have you tried running in the debugger, or enabling address sanitizer?

Comment: Tip: Errors should be sent to stderr, not stdout. Simply replace `printf( ... )` with `fprintf( stderr, ... )`

Comment: Post a _minimal_ example please. You need to narrow down the problem. For example have a peek at the call stack at the point when you get the stack smash bug.

Comment: I put some info from the debuggers

Answer (score -1):

### Well that really unreadable.

I look your code and **i didn't find** the error, and that not surprising.

At some point project become so big, it's really hard to find a bug, even more if you not in the project.

That also why pp ask for **a minimal example**.

I think, is time for you to take a good look at tool like `valgrind`, `fsanitize`, `gdb`, ext.

And why create 2 thread/philo, and not you not using your main to check death?
What you gonna do in your main anyway?

*Welcome in the 42 family.*

Comment: This could be a comment, but doesn't look as an answer.